# Splitting a string into equals parts (java/groovy)

Tags: java, groovy

I'd like to split the string into substrings which has 20 chars (or less for the tail). Is there some library or I need to make the class for that?

Comment: Just use substring. There may *be* a library function somewhere which does this, but it's sufficiently easy to do that I wouldn't spend too long looking for it.

Comment: %) apparently, however with `groovy` it could be even easier. Will wait for other replies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should use :

```
s.split("(?<=\\G.{20})");
```

`\G` is a zero-width assertion that matches the position where the previous match ended. If there was no previous match, it matches the beginning of the input, the same as `\A`. The enclosing lookbehind matches the position that's 20 characters along from the end of the last match.

Comment: Thanks for both answers.

Answer (score 4):

Or, with Groovy you could do:

```
assert 'abcdefghij'.toList().collate( 3 )*.join() == ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'j']
```