# Splitting string into n-length elements for an array

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string

How would I split a string into equal parts using `String.split()` provided the string is full of numbers? For the sake of example, each part in the below is of size 5.

```
"123" would be split into "123"
"12345" would be split into "12345"
"123451" would be split into "12345" and "1"
"123451234512345" would be split into "12345", "12345" and "12345"
etc
```

These are to be put in an array:

```
String myString = "12345678";
String[] myStringArray = myString.split(???);
//myStringArray => "12345", "678";
```

I'm just unsure the regex to use, nor how to separate it into equal sized chunks.

Comment: I don't see how `"12345", "1"` are equal sized chunks.

Comment: And what if the string contains characters other than numbers? What should happen?

Comment: @RohitJain, I guess what I'm looking for is a method to split a string every 5th position. fge, I have a check for characters already which throws an exception.

Comment: @RohitJain He doesn't look for equal size, he looks for equal pattern sub-strings.

Comment: @riista What happens for `1234567123`?

Comment: @RohitJain, it would be split to `12345` and `67123`. I care not for the contents within, I only care for the size.

Comment: Use substring with start and end index.

Comment: @riista Ok, then I guess you've already got an answer.

Comment: So,Do you look for sub-strings with length of 5?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915686/splitting-a-string-into-equals-parts-java-groovy/18915872#18915872

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this way

```
String input = "123451234512345";
String[] pairs = input.split("(?<=\\G\\d{5})");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pairs));
```

Output:

```
[12345, 12345, 12345]
```

This regex uses [positive look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism `(?<=...)` and `\\G` which represents "previous match - place where previously matched string ends, or if it doesn't exist yet (when we just started matching) `^` which is start of the string".

So regex will match any place that has five digits before it and before this five digits previously matched place we split on.

Comment: +1 An explanation might help better :)

Comment: @RohitJain was in the middle of writing it :)

Comment: +1 spot on with use of `\\G`

Comment: Cheers. Will this also take into consideration where the `input` is less than 5 digits?

Comment: @riista Yes. Just try it?

Comment: Worth mentioning here that lookarounds, as all other anchors, do not consume any text; necessary since `.split()` normally consumes the delimiter

Comment: @riista Yes. Result for `"123"` is `[123]`. This regex decide to split only after first 5 digits, so if there will be none it will not split.

Comment: Worth also mentioning what `\G` really does, that is "start where previous match left off"; since the regex doesn't consume any text, if there were no `\G` here, it would start at the next character, since regex engines shift by one character if the match is empty (which it is here). But that may be quite a lot to explain... In any case, +1

Comment: @fge Thanks, as always your comments are very helpful. +1